# Python Terminology Regarding Function Input and Output

Tags: python, function, input, output, terminology

Very simple question but always wondered what the answer was;

In the same way that we have that the terminology for the input into a function being the argument, what is the terminology for the output received???

Also, if a function simply performs a process without directly passing data back out, such as arranging a file in the way you wish for it to be done, then what is the terminology for this???

Cheers

Comment: The former I'd call the return value or the result, but I don't think it's totally standardized. The latter are referred to as side effects, consistently. Except that changing a passed it parameter is sometimes referred to as mutating it - as in 'calling `sort` on a list mutates its input.' That said, there's no external authority so different people will put things differently.

Comment: A stylistic comment. A single `?` is sufficient at the end of a question. The extra `?`s make your sentences appear juvenile. Also, the "Cheers" is unnecessary on SO.

Comment: ok im sorry Noufal Ibrahim for being juvenile

Answer (score 2):

I remember reading back in the day that subroutines which return values were referred to as *functions* (from the mathematical term) and those that don't were called *subroutines* or *procedures*. Arguments or parameters are the things passed into a function. What it returns is called a *return value* or simply the *value* of the function.